# Flutter is getting yellow instead of black. How can I solve it

Tags: flutter, dart

Even though I chose black in the marked area that I showed in the photo from the color part in Flutter, the color comes out yellow. This situation is the same in both Visual Studio Cod and Android Studio. What could be the reason?
Also, the theme's default font color should be black, but it's yellow. Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4ECy.jpg)

Comment: Please retag your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

InputDecoration has property hintStyle there you can set color for you hintText

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
        ),
      ),
```

Or you can set input decoration in the theme as below

```
inputDecorationTheme:const InputDecorationTheme(
hintStyle:TextStyle(color:Colors.grey)
```

)

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem Solved for now. However, even though I choose Colors.black from the color palette, the yellow color comes out. What would be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt0rR.jpg)Thank you so much. Problem Solved for now. However, even though I choose Colors.black from the color palette, the yellow color comes out. What would be the reason.

Comment: Please use the comment feature to communicate with an answer.